# Reference Error with module exports event discord.js

Tags: sql, node.js, discord.js

I am very confused by this error. In my code I have /events/ and /commands/ this is in /events/ I made sure that everything else works but this I can't figure out. The code down below is meant to work as a server count for a website. Anybody know? Thank you.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

var db = require('mysql');


var con = db.createConnection({
   host: "localhost",
   user: "",
   password: "",
   database: ""
});


module.exports = (client, guildCreate) => {
//welcome embed
 const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#858884')
       .setTitle('Hello!')
       .setAuthor('DHL Bot', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/app-icons/708717412391845988/967e1b05f7b8aeca1d6b4649dc5530c8.png')
       .setDescription(`Hello I am DHL, I am devoloped by Den#0762. Please do !setup. For support you can join our support server https://discord.com/invite`)
       .setTimestamp()
       .setFooter('By: Den#0762', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/407206318911258628/e972b589e0ea4c45064d39b0380d77fd.png')
guild.owner.send(welcomeEmbed)
//db for scount
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
 var sql = "UPDATE scount SET servercount = servercount + 1";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result.affectedRows + " new server");
  });
});
}
```

```
(node:1949) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: guild is not defined
   at module.exports (/root/dc/DHL/events/guildCreate.js:23:1)
   at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
   at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_CREATE] (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_CREATE.js:33:14)
   at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
   at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
   at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
   at WebSocket.onMessage (/root/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
   at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
   at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/root/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:797:20)
   at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1949) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1949) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: as it clearly say `guild ` is not defined so figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `guild`, but it isn't declared. Based on other code I've seen, I think you need something along these lines:

```
module.exports = (client, guildCreate) => {
    //welcome embed
    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() [...]
 
    client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
        guild.owner.send(welcomeEmbed)
    });

    [...]
```